# Displaying a List of controls Wpf Mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am planning to display a List of text and color (legends) on my Wpf Window in Mvvm way.  Like this in image

[image]

Here is my code

```
public class LegendsViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Collection<Legends> LegendsDataCollection { get; set; }

    public LegendsViewModel()
    {
      LegendsDataCollection = Legends.GetLegendsCollection();
    }
}

public class Legends
{
    public string Name;
    public Brush LegendsBrush;
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }

    public static ObservableCollection<Legends> GetLegendsCollection()
    {
        var legends = new ObservableCollection<Legends>();

        legends.Add(new Legends { Name = "Failure", LegendsBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(226, 125, 40)), X = 9, Y = 250, Height = 28, Width = 36 });
        legends.Add(new Legends { Name = "Online", LegendsBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(40, 201, 226)), X = 9, Y = 285, Height = 28, Width = 36 });
        legends.Add(new Legends { Name = "Power On", LegendsBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0)), X = 9, Y = 320, Height = 28, Width = 36 });
        legends.Add(new Legends { Name = "Power Off", LegendsBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(156, 169, 169)), X = 355, Y = 243, Height = 28, Width = 36 });
        legends.Add(new Legends { Name = "Error", LegendsBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0)), X = 9, Y = 390, Height = 28, Width = 36 });

        return legends;
    }
}

public partial class LegendsView : UserControl
{
    public LegendsView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new LegendsViewModel();
    }
}
```

And here is my LegendsView.xaml code

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="Panel" MinWidth="150">
       <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LegendsDataCollection}">
          <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 <Canvas />
             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
             <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Fill="{Binding LegendsBrush}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       </ItemsControl>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

But it is not at all displaying anything, Where I am going Wrong ?

Edit : I solved it using this code & suggestion from @Clemens

```
 <DataTemplate>
     <Grid x:Name="GridItem" Width="200">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Width}"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Height="{Binding Height}" Fill="{Binding LegendsBrush}"/>
       <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="15,1,0,0" />
   </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Do you anywhere set the DataContext (e.g. of the Window) to a LegendsViewModel instance? And is `LegendsDataCollection` actually a public property (not a field) in class LegendsViewModel? Do you observe binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio?

Comment: 1) Are you sure your ItemsControl is bound to the ViewModel? 2) Are you sure LegendsDataCollection is initialized **before** ItemsControl is?

Comment: @Clemens, I have updated my question and included all code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LegendsBrush` is not a property, but a field. WPF data binding only works with public properties.

Class `Legends` should look like this:

```
public class Legends
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Brush LegendsBrush { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Hence, no `Fill`, no view.

---

In order to also display the value of the `Name` property, you may change your DataTemplate like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"
          Background="{Binding LegendsBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Aah, I can see my Coloured brushes now. Any idea how can I see the Text as well, "Failure" etc.  I know I haven't included that ion xaml code. but How can i see that text as well aligned with brush

Comment: Now I can see the text on the grid itself with Colored Background . It is not as displayed in the picture.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens, I solved it myself, I have updated my question with the answer also.